# Angular long generated url when opening a Pdf file

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm using Angula 4 in order to open a Pdf file in the browser, the file is opened but  the generated url in the navigation bar is too lonng which contains the binary stream

eg:

[Url example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuMQ3.png)

```
openPdfFile() {
    this.documentService
      .getProjetPdf(this.projet.id)
      .subscribe(document => window.open('data:application/pdf;base64, ' + 
   document.data));
  }
```

Any idea how can i rewrite this url to be more clear and clean.

Thanks

Comment: The only way to make a data URI smaller is to make the data smaller.